# How to use Group in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I got one list from LinQ Query, I would like to check the count of `SuiteId` if each Count = 3 then return me that `suiteId` how can I solve it?

```
   var a = _context.SuiteReserveAvailables.Where(c =>
                    c.AvailableDate <= DtpEnd.SelectedDateTime &&
                    c.AvailableDate >= DtpStart.SelectedDateTime &&
                    c.ReserveStatus == false && c.IsDeleted == false && c.IsActive)
                    .Select(c => c.SuiteId).ToList();
```

For ex : Result is {1,1,1,3,3,2,5,5,5,5} so i need only `1` number because 3 time reapeted in my list

Comment: how is your LINQ statement related to your question? To get a value that is repeated `N` times you need to use `GroupBy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = _context.SuiteReserveAvailables.Where(c =>
                    c.AvailableDate <= DtpEnd.SelectedDateTime &&
                    c.AvailableDate >= DtpStart.SelectedDateTime &&
                    c.ReserveStatus == false && c.IsDeleted == false && c.IsActive)
                    .GroupBy(c => c.SuiteId)
                    .Where(gr => gr.Count() == 3)
                    .Select(gr => gr.Key)
                    .ToList();
```

That should do it.